# PHP is returning blank page, even ignores echo/print

Tags: php

I'm trying to produce a simple PHP script that queries an SQL database and outputs some data, however it is showing a blank page.

Now ordinarily I would assume there is something wrong with my code, but I have tried turning on error reporting by heading my code with

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
  session_start();
```

and have also tried throwing in just a simple `echo "yes";` at the top of the code, yet when I visit the page I still receive a blank screen.

Surely even if there is a problem with the rest of my code it would a) still print 'yes' or b) return an error?

Here is the source code, minus the authentication variables:

```
$id = $_GET('id');

  // Connect and create the PDO object
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

  // Define and perform the SQL query
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `obits` WHERE `id` = $id";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

print_r ($result);


$conn = null;        // Disconnect
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is causing the problem?

Comment: Check the server side error log...

Comment: If the script won't compile, it will return a blank page (and typically an ERROT 500) - check your webserver error logs

Comment: don't change error_reporting in your script. it presumes things are working well enough for your script to even get executed. While developing/debugging, you should have error_reporting/display_errors turned on at the php.ini level.

Comment: Surely you have a syntax error, thus PHP parser can't even reach your first line of code.

Comment: view source (in case its all the php)

Comment: Probably related to OP's [`other question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21584324/) - [`See comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584324/why-wont-my-upload-script-work-no-errors#comment32606470_21584403)

Comment: There is an error on page and error display is off from server side. This result a blank page. To test remove all the code from the file and just echo test message.

Comment: I have edited to include my source code

Comment: I take it that you have the creds. already set for `$hostdb` `$namedb` `$userdb` `$passdb` variables? @James - I.e.: 
`$mysql_hostname = 'xxx'; $mysql_username = 'xxx'; $mysql_password = 'xxx'; $mysql_dbname = 'xxx'; $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);`

Comment: A blank page is either the result of nothing in DB, improper DB setup, or invalid query. You haven't responded to my earlier comment, so I'll take a stab in saying it's a mix of all of these.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you didn't ask a question, sorry.

Comment: You mean [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710761/php-is-returning-blank-page-even-ignores-echo-print?noredirect=1#comment32831454_21710761) isn't a question?

Comment: Sorry I was looking at your previous comment. Yes those are set, I did say in my OP `Here is the source code, minus the authentication variables:` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have error logging configured to route somewhere else other than to the screen.  Try running your script from shell and see if that outputs any errors.

```
$bash: php script.php
```

Often times, that will give you the errors if the browser won't.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including anything before this script runs?

If an included script contains a syntax error, it will return 500 to the client.

That might explain why you are unable to "echo" anything.